# What kind of uniqueness can I conclude for solutions to a simple functional equation?

Tags: functional-equations, differential-equations, mp.mathematical-physics

I'm going to ask a very vague question, and then give specifics for the version I particularly care about.  I'm interested in answers at all levels of vagueness.

At the most vague version, I am in the following situation.  I have some particular (smooth) function $A(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1)$, where $t_0,t_1$ are real variables and $q_0,q_1$ vary over some manifold $M$, i.e. $A: \mathbb R \times M \times \mathbb R \times M \to \mathbb R$.  I have another (smooth) function $Q(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1;t) : \mathbb R \times M \times \mathbb R \times M  \times \mathbb R \to M$.
  I am interested in (smooth) solutions $F(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1)$ to the "composition" formula:
$$ A(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1)\,F(t_0,q_0,t,Q(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1;t))\,F(t,Q(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1;t),t_1,q_1) = F(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1)$$
I know one such (nonzero) solution explicitly.  I am hoping that, presumably with slightly more data (some sort of "initial data"), I can conclude that my solution is uniquely determined.  So my question is:

> What extra data for $F$, and what restrictions on $A$, are needed for a functional equation of the above type to have a unique solution?

---

For those interested, I can give you more precise information.  I have some "physics" encoded by a function $S(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1)$, which I am thinking of as a "Hamilton-Jacobi function".  This function defines $Q$ via:
$$ \left. \frac{\partial}{\partial q} \bigl[ S(t_0,q_0,t,q) + S(t,q,t_1,q_1) \bigr] \right]_{q = Q(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1;t)} = 0 $$
and satisfies:
$$ S(t_0,q_0,t,q) + S(t,q,t_1,q_1) \bigr|_{q = Q(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1;t)} = S(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1)$$
The function $A$ is given by
$$ \left| \det \left[ \frac{\partial^2}{\partial q^2} \bigl[ S(t_0,q_0,t,q) + S(t,q,t_1,q_1) \bigr] \right]_{q = Q(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1;t)}  \right|^{-1/2} $$
Then the function $F$ is:
$$ F(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1) = \left| \det \frac{\partial^2}{\partial q_0\partial q_1} \bigl[ S(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1) \bigr]  \right|^{1/2}$$
which as defined makes sense only on $\mathbb R^n$.  Actually, $A$ makes sense as a volume form, and $F$ as a half density in each variable, and then everything transforms correctly under changes of coordinates.

Anyway, I would really like to conclude that this $F$ is the only solution, but I don't know if I can.

Comment: Incidentally, checking the slightly more explicit case is a nice exercise, or see my papers on the arXiv :)  In any case, probably I should have written the original equation I want to solve logarithmically as `$a + f_0 + f_1 = f_{01}$`, to make it even more clear that I do not expect there to be a unique solution --- multiply the original `$F(t_0,q_0,t_1,q_1)$` by `$e^{\lambda(t_1 - t_0)}$` for any $\lambda$, for example.  But I do expect that there's a "small" family, like is the case for differential equations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a vague answer then: there's [an old 1978 paper in Aequationes Mathematicae](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01818567) mentioning the problem of uniqueness for the functional equation $\varphi (x)=h(x,\varphi [f_1(x)],\dots, \varphi [f_n(x)] )$ under some hypotheses. This seems to be of the same form as your equation (identifying $x=(q_0,t_0,q_1,t_1)$ and so on). Maybe what you're looking for is in there, or in later papers quoting that one.

Having said that, since your inspiration is Hamiltonian mechanics, I would imagine at least some variant of your problem to have been investigated already. Obviously you're looking at the stationary phase approximation to the quantum propagator, such as in [equation (33.32) of a chapter about the semiclassical propagator](https://chaosbook.org/chapters/VanVleck.pdf) in a [great physics textbook](https://chaosbook.org/).   Now there's been a lot of mathematical work on the topic which may, at least implicitly, help you with your specific question, namely [this paper of Meinrenken](https://lib-extopc.kek.jp/preprints/PDF/1992/9201/9201019.pdf) in particular page 7 and beyond, and [that paper](https://web.ma.utexas.edu/mp_arc-bin/mpa?yn=97-599) of Combescure–Ralston–Robert.